# r-forecast package in conda jupyter

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to take advantage of the Juypter notebook with the R kernel. R-essentials via conda does not include the forecast package.

However someone has seemed to create one:

https://anaconda.org/r/r-forecast

I have installed the package with conda install -c r r-forecast=7.3 per the directions. Seems to install without issue.

When I launch the R kernel in Jupyter and attach the forecast library, it starts off fine and then errors. However I can't understand what the error means to even begin a fix.

Thoughts?

[image]

Comment: It seems that the loading process for timeDate package failed. What if you load timeDate package alone?

Comment: timeDate loads/attaches fine. Then I load the forecast library in the next cell and it gives the exact same error message. MPG